# Degeneracy of term symbols

Tags: physical-chemistry

Hello I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAgEmLWpYjs&ab_channel=T.DanielCrawford) where term symbols are explained in detail. Moreover, he gives following illustration of a 2p1 state of hydrogen:

[image]

His calculation for the degeneracy is correct, however, how can I know which of the 6 electronic configurations corresponds to which term symbol?

For example, I don't understand why the $^{2}\text{P}_{1/2}$ state only has 2 states of the six. For example, look at the last state of the left row. If you add L=-1 to s=+1/2 you also get J=1/2. If you calculate every state through, you end with four states with J=1/2 and two J=3/2.

Where is my mistake? Or does one take the absolute value of L before adding it to S?

Comment: I have a feeling I know what you are asking, and I would like to answer if I can (if I'm right, I found this problem equally confusing), but the way you've written it makes it hard to tell. Could you edit your question to include explicit superscripts and subscripts? (Also, shouldn't one of those term symbols be $^2P_{\frac{3}{2}}$?)

Comment: You are correct, I typed one term symbol wrong. Edited accordingly

Comment: You can write $^{2}\text{P}_{1/2}$ or $^{2}\text{P}_{\frac{1}{2}}$ as `$^{2}\text{P}_{1/2}$` or `$^{2}\text{P}_{\frac{1}{2}}$`

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What do you think about this reference from the University of Santa Barbara in California? (Term symbols: why bother?)[https://web.chem.ucsb.edu/~devries/chem218/Term%20symbols.pdf];  Also what do you think of this reference? [Term symbol](https://www.chemeurope.com/en/encyclopedia/Term_symbol.html)?

Comment: First link is dead:(

Comment: A hydrogen atom was probably not a very good way to explain term symbols, because it doesn't show how the different quantum numbers relate to each other, and doesn't show the degeneracy well... If you can find it, I would highly recommend you look up Herzberg's _Atomic Spectra and Atomic Structure_; it explains everything _very_ clearly.

Answer (score 1):

> If you add L=-1 to s=+1/2 you also get J=1/2

The main issue is that you are not being careful in distinguishing between $L$, which corresponds to the magnitude of angular momentum, and $M_L$, which denotes the orientation of the angular momentum (strictly its projection onto the $z$-axis).

When you write $+1, 0, -1$ on the p-orbitals these correspond to $M_L$, not $L$. (You might have seen the notation $m_l$; the small letters correspond to quantum numbers for a single electron, whereas $M_L$ signifies the sum of $m_l$'s. In this case there is only one electron, so they are the same thing.)

On the other hand, $L$ for a $\mathrm{2p^1}$ configuration is *always* $+1$, no more, no less. An electron in a p-orbital carries one unit of orbital angular momentum. (Again, you may have seen this denoted as $l$. In the one-electron case, $L$ is the same as $l$. With two electrons you have $L = |l_1 - l_2|, \ldots, l_1 + l_2$.)

The relationship between $L$ and $M_L$ is that for each value of $L$, the allowed value of $M_L$ ranges from $-L$ to $L$ in steps of $1$, which is exactly what you see in the statement $M_L = -1, 0, 1$.

The same is true of $S$ and $M_S$: the spin-up electron has $M_S = +1/2$ and the spin-down has $M_S = -1/2$, but both of these have $S = 1/2$.

Once you have $L$ and $S$, you obtain $J$ by the formula:

$$J = |L - S|, \ldots, L+S$$

in steps of $1$, which gives us $1/2$ and $3/2$. However, each $J$ term comprises several states which (again) have $M_J = -J, \ldots, J$. So:

- The $^2\!P_{3/2}$ term comprises four states with $M_J = -3/2, -1/2, +1/2, +3/2$.
- The $^2\!P_{3/2}$ term comprises two states with $M_J = -1/2, +1/2$.

How do you identify these states?

Because $M_J$ is a projection of the orbital angular momentum, as opposed to a magnitude, it can be obtained by simply summing up the projections of the two sources. In other words,

$$M_J = M_S + M_L.$$

You can now identify the state that has $M_S = +1/2$ and $M_L = +1$: it's the top-left one in your diagram. This state has $M_J = +3/2$ and thus must belong to the $J = 3/2$ term.

Likewise, you can find the state with $M_J = -3/2$ (bottom right); that must also belong to the $J = 3/2$ term.

The rest are slightly more complicated. You can't use a similar argument to assign the $M_J = \pm 1/2$ states to terms because both $J = 1/2$ and $J = 3/2$ can admit $M_J = \pm 1/2$. I'm fairly sure that you need to take linear combinations of the remaining states before you can map them to terms.

If you need to know this, it's probably worth a separate question (assuming it doesn't already exist somewhere here). However, I would strongly advise you to be comfortable with the various forms of angular momenta (magnitude / projection) before moving on to that.